# how to pass input and configurations files by using linux command

Tags: c++, linux, parameters, command-line-arguments

I have an executable file `vs-vectorize` for which I want to pass a f**ile to analyze** along side its configuration files. I am Very very new to linux so excuse my question.

---

The file to analyze is in xml format:

```
<doc id="E0211315">
<text>
Gimme Dat

For the Chris Brown song, see Gimme That

"Gimme Dat" is the second single released off of Chingy's fourth album, Hate It
or Love It. The single features Ludacris and Bobby Valentino.

The video premiered on MTV's TRL and BET's 106 & Park on February 8, 2008. The
song however failed to chart making it his second consecutive single flop from
the album.

 Charts
</text>
</doc>
```

---

The parameters are the following:

```
Usage:
  vectorize --conf=.. --language=.. [--xml-conf=..] --output=.. files 
Options:
  -h [ --help ]         Display this help message
  --conf arg            XML config file
  --xml-conf arg        configuration file for xml analysis (to interpret xml 
                        format of input file)
  --language arg        language of the documents
  --output arg          prefix of the files for outputs


--conf
This option allows to specify the name of the configuration file to use: this file contains all the parameters used for the different steps of the construction of the vector representation (Analyzers, LexiconBuilder, VectorBuilder). More details on the content of the configuration file are given in this page: Configuration File.

--xml-conf
This option allows to specify the name of a configuration file that indicates how to parse the xml input file. This configuration file should respect the XML format defined here: XML Format for the input file parser configuration.

--language
This option specifies the language of the documents (useful in the linguistic analysis step).

--output
This option specifies the base name for the output files created by this program. The main output file containing the vectors will be base.data. If this argument is not set, the base name of the first input file is used (without .xml or .txt extension).
```

---

I am passing the arguments as follows:

```
./vs-vectorize documents.xml --conf vs-config.xml --xml-conf configuration.xml
```

Where documents.xml is the input file to analyze and others are the parameter files.

Some modification:

```
./vs-vectorize --conf="/home/hani/workspace/textvector/conf/vs-config.xml" --language="Eng" --xml-conf="/home/hani/workspace/textvector/release/src/vs-vectorize/configuration.xml" /home/hani/workspace/textvector/release/src/vs-vectorize/documents.xml
```

---

Nothing is coming out why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this `./vs-vectorize --conf="vs-config.xml" --xml-conf="configuration.xml" documents.xml`

Comment: @Dragan can I skip for example the --language option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the full path of the files eg: /home/hani/documents.xml instead of just the file name.